# USB external drive does not show if it is in hibernation mode in Debian

Tags: debian, hdparm

Good companions. I'm trying to find out if one of my hard drives has gone into hibernation (or sleep) mode but my thumb drive always shows this:

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/disk/by-uuid/E2C2A877C2A61FB1

/dev/disk/by-uuid/E2C2A877C2A61FB1:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 drive state is:  standby
```

I'm using **Openmediavault (Debian)** and from there I put the disk to hibernate after 60 minutes, but I have no way of finding out if it has really gone into hibernation since it always puts stanby. Despite the fact that it appears as standby, I can access the disk immediately, that is, it is not in hibernation mode. My drive is a **Seagate backup plus Hub BK**.

The disk being active should show this with **hdparm -C**:

```
drive state is:  active/idle
```

What happens to this disk? how could i find out if it is really hibernating? Thank you very much

EDIT: With the command **smartctl -i -n standby** suggested by the colleague @mashuptwice gives me this information, but it doesn't seem to show if the drive is hibernated or awake.

```
root@NAS:~# smartctl -i -n standby /dev/disk/by-uuid/E2C2A877C2A61FB1
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-5.10.0-0.bpo.11-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Seagate
Product:              Backup+ Hub BK
Revision:             D781
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        8.001.563.221.504 bytes [8,00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x5000000000000001
Serial number:        NA8TR3BY
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Sun Mar 20 19:44:04 2022 CET
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Disabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

root@NAS:~#
```

Comment: Check if you can physically feel it spinning? I'm not sure if there is any real difference between "standby" vs "sleep" for HDDs, it's either spinning or not.

Comment: According to my other external drive, when it goes into hibernation it stops spinning

Comment: Check the output of `hdparm -C` after running `hdparm -Y`

Comment: note `hdparm -C` could wake up the disk in some cases. You might want to check with `smartctl -i -n standby`

Comment: I just tried that command but it doesn't seem to return information about the state of the disk (if it is in standby or active). I'm going to put the output of that command in the OP message.

Comment: @PlayerWet could be because you've disabled SMART. I get a line as following: `Power mode is:    ACTIVE or IDLE`. Note that this wasn't the important part of my comment. It would be more interesting to see if your drive goes to sleep with `hdparm -Y`. Also hear and feel if the disk spins down like suggested by user1686.

Comment: With hdparm -Y I get this response:

/dev/disk/by-uuid/E2C2A877C2A61FB1:
 issuing sleep command
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

The disc keeps spinning like nothing happened.

Comment: I've found an excellent OMV forum post about your exact problem filled with nice suggestions on what to try next. You can find it [here](https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/27476-external-hdd-won-t-spin-down-works-fine-under-windows-macos-ubuntu-fritzos/)

Comment: Try to enable full SATA support including S.M.A.R.T. features with following command: `sudo echo "0bc2:ab38:" > /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks`. Copy the file before doing that. (Found in [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768373/hard-drive-error-bad-missing-sense-data).)

Comment: I am afraid of losing the data on the disk. They are not important and there is a backup, but there are many and it would take me time to replicate them again. Is there a risk with the recommendations that you have given me? Thanks.